# Проверка на содержание внутри контейнера Js

Tags: javascript

У меня есть контейнер, который есть у всех моих объектов, он имеет класс. Внутри него у почти всех элементов также есть другие блоки с классами, но не у всех. И вот мне нужно вывести как-то содержимое именно этих внутренних блоков, но там, где этого блока, просто выводить "значения нет". Я думал сделать это на проверку на содержание у общего контейнера этого блока.

Условно говоря, у меня нечто вроде такого:

```
<div class="first-container">
    <div class="optional-container">
    content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="second-container">
    <!-- здесь этот блок отсутствует -->
</div>
<div class="third-container">
    <div class="optional-container">
    content
    </div>
</div>
```

Ну вот и контент из optional-container'ов мне надо вывести, но если этого блока нет, то просто вывести что ничего нет

Answer (score 0):

> мне нужно вывести как-то содержимое именно этих внутренних блоков, но там, где этого блока, просто выводить "значения нет"

Довольно странная организация классов... Вроде бы блоки однотипные но общего класса им не дали. Можно было бы оттолкнуться от общего родителя... Но про него так же нет ни слова.

Т.ч. предложу вот такой вариант получения текста.

```js
const sel = '[class$="-container"]:not(.optional-container)'
const a = [...document.querySelectorAll(sel)].map(o => {
  return o.querySelector('.optional-container')?.textContent ?? 'значения нет'
})
console.log(a)
```

```html
<div class="first-container">
    <div class="optional-container">
    content 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="second-container">
    <!-- здесь этот блок отсутствует -->
</div>
<div class="third-container">
    <div class="optional-container">
    content 2
    </div>
</div>
```